# Angular app-routing.module.ts: - error TS2322: Type '"enabled"' is not assignable to type 'InitialNavigation | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-start

After I upgrade my project from Angular 11 to 14, I faced following error on "ng serve".

```
Error: src/app/app-routing.module.ts:107:7 - error TS2322: Type '"enabled"' is not assignable to type 'InitialNavigation | undefined'.

107       initialNavigation: 'enabled',
```

related code part of app-routing.module.ts is following.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

The project is worked well on Angular 11.
How can I fix this issue for angular 14?

Answer (score 5):

In version 14 of Angular, 'enabled' is not an option anymore.

According to the official documentation [link](https://angular.io/api/router/InitialNavigation)

These are the options now:

- 'enabledNonBlocking' - (default) The initial navigation starts after
  the root component has been created. The bootstrap is not blocked on
  the completion of the initial navigation.
- 'enabledBlocking' - The initial navigation starts before the root
  component is created. The bootstrap is blocked until the initial
  navigation is complete. This value is required for server-side
  rendering to work.
- 'disabled' - The initial navigation is not performed. The location
  listener is set up before the root component gets created. Use if
  there is a reason to have more control over when the router starts
  its initial navigation due to some complex initialization logic.

So..
You only have to change

```
initialNavigation: 'enabled',
```

for

```
initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking',
```

or

```
initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
```

according to your needs.